# How to call other module component function from app component

Tags: angular

My application has app module and dashboard module, dashboard module has lot of components. I have to trigger the dashboard component function(changedivStatus) from app component.

I hope this can be achieve by service  with EventEmitter by emit and subscribe.

Is there any other way without service.

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }                     from '@angular/core';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule }                from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule,NoopAnimationsModule}       from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DashboardModule }              from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
```

> dashboard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }               from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }          from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule }         from '@angular/router';
import { WidgetsModule }          from '../widgets/widgets.module';
import { SharedModule }          from '../shared/shared.module';
import { DashboardComponent }     from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AppSelectorComponent }   from './app-selector/app-selector.component';
import { AppReportsComponent }   from './app-reports/app-reports.component';
import {AppReportsService} from '../shared/services/app-reports.service';
import { BsDropdownModule }   from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatSidenavModule,MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material';
import {CheckboxModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        SharedModule,
        WidgetsModule,
        BsDropdownModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        CheckboxModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatDatepickerModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        AppSelectorComponent,
        AppReportsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AppReportsService
    ],
    exports: [
        DashboardComponent
    ]
})

export class DashboardModule {

}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div class="reports_container fRight" *ngIf="!firstVisit">
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="changedivStatus()" class="md-primary" [checked]="showReport" />
    <span style="font-size: 12px">Hide Banner</span>
</div>
```

> dashborad.component.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <app-app-reports [items]="apps" *ngIf="loadReport"></app-app-reports>
</div>
</div>
```

> dashboard.component.ts

```
changedivStatus() {
        this.showReport = !this.showReport;
        if(!this.showReport) {
            this.loadReport = true;
        } else {
            this.loadReport = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a service for this?

Comment: Just a note, dont take 'angularjs' in this, that is the first iteration of angular and is very different from Angular 2+ (which is tagged as 'angular')

Comment: I have to include the services in app module too, for avoiding the include of the service trying with only component.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it (and you should) using services, by putting your `changeDivStatus()` function in a dashboard.service, triggering it from your app.component, emitting the event from your dashboard.service and subscribing to this event in your dashboard.component `ngOnInit` function.

Here's the official angular guide for services : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4